# Nginx don't rewrite certain URL's

Tags: nginx, url-rewriting

Right now I'm rewriting all http requests to Page.php with

```
rewrite ^ Page.php last;
```

But I want to allow to access file from /Ajax/ folder directly.
I tried adding (at the beginning)

```
rewrite /Ajax/SamplePage.php /Ajax/SamplePage.php last; (for example)
```

But still landed on Page.php

Is there any way to write something like

```
rewrite ^/Ajax/ - last;
```

?

Answer (score 0):

You can try:

```
rewrite ^(?!(/Ajax/))(.*)$ /Page.php last;
```